# how to filter more than once in Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog()

Tags: wpf, winforms

```
    Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
dlg.FileName = "Document"; // Default file name
dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt"; // Default file extension
dlg.Filter = "Text documents (.txt)|*.txt"; // Filter files by extension here
```

I want to filter more than one type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.filedialog.filter.aspx:

> For each filtering option, the filter string contains a description of
>   the filter, followed by the vertical bar (|) and the filter pattern.
>   The strings for different filtering options are separated by the
>   vertical bar.
>
> The following is an example of a filter string:
>
> `Text files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*`